# netbeans says cannot find include file <conio.h>

Tags: c++, netbeans, header-files

I'm in trouble and need help. I just installed the required Devel packages of the cygwin installation in order to run c++. I'm using netbeans as my development environment but I don't know why it can't locate the conio.h header file or am I missing something? thanks in advance

Comment: `conio.h` is a system-specific include file for Windows. It's available in the Windows SDK.

Comment: Thanks. Please, how then should I include it in my project? I'm running windows 8.1

Comment: Why do you use cygwin?

Comment: Because I was advised to do so. I'm new to c++

Comment: Cygwin is not C++. Why where you advised to use it?

Comment: Because it contains the Devel packages which contains the g++ compiler, make utility and the gdb debugger. Uhm! please am I missing something?

Comment: Those are all utilities that are used for compiling Linux-based applications that run on Windows. You can't easily switch it to use Windows-based standard library, headers, object files and more - they're designed to explicitly not be able to do that. The easiest solution would be to get the latest [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/vs/community/). As an additional recommendation, you may want to update your computer to a more recent OS such as Windows 10 1709.

Comment: A million Thanks @tambre

Comment: Cygwin is used to run Linux programs on Windows. But `<conio.h>` indicates that you already have a Windows (or DOS really) program, and now sort of try to run a Windows program on Linux (on Windows). Makes it a bit backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cygwin is designed to let you run Linux programs on Windows. This is also often used for one to be able to use Linux development tools.

[`conio.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is a C header file, which declares a few I/O functions available only on Windows. It's part of the Windows SDK. Cygwin is not designed to be able to link Windows object files or be able to use WinAPI - it's designed to do the exact opposite.

The easiest way for you to do development on Windows is to use [Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/de/downloads). Make sure to install C++ support and the Windows SDK during installation.